# PHP's strtotime() does not add to dates as I expected

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I think I am correct in saying that `strtotime(2023)` will return the number of seconds from 1 Jan 1970 to 1 Jan 2023.

I thought I could then add a year to that value like this: `strtotime('+1 year', strtotime(2023))`. I assume that the the number of seconds added  would take into account whether it is a leap year or not and even whether any leap seconds need to be accounted for. However I am not sure if that assumption is correct.

If my assumptions were correct then the value should be the same as `strtotime(2024)`. When I do it I find the ouputs are not the same.

The code I have run and the output is shown below:

```
<?php
$tsFrom = strtotime(2023);
$tsTo = strtotime('+1 year', $tsFrom);
echo $tsTo;
echo ' | ';
echo strtotime(2024);

// output:
// 1705436580 | 1673900640
```

I ran the code on the sandbox at https://onlinephp.io/

I tried putting the argument to `strtotime()` in quotes as I know normally it would take a string but that makes no difference to the output.

I would like to know where I am going wrong

Comment: `2023` is being evaluated as the hour/minute, not the year: https://3v4l.org/dK5JM

Comment: how can I supply just the year as an argument (if that is possible)?

Comment: UNIX timestamps are precise to the second, it's vague what a "timestamp of 2023" should look like. If you mean midnight of Jan. 1st 2023, then provide all that as input.

Comment: You can pass in the string `2023-01-01` and it will default to the first of the year

Comment: Thanks. That would definitely work for me but is it not possible to just supply the year?

Comment: @aynber I have verified that it does work now I supply `2023-01-01`.

Comment: Apparently that's not the way it works. [This is the original C++ code for strtotime](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/lib/parse_date.c#L25951), if you want to look through it

Answer (score -3):

```
strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime(' + 1 years')))
```

or

```
 strtotime(date('2022-01-16', strtotime(' + 1 years')))
```